# AWSSQS trying to create queue and get messages

Tags: objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to connect to AWS SQS to create a new queue and also fetch messages I've placed on a another queue. This is the code I'm using:

```
    AWSSQS *sqs=[[AWSSQS alloc] initWithConfiguration:configuration];

    AWSSQSCreateQueueRequest *createQueue = [[AWSSQSCreateQueueRequest alloc] init];
    [createQueue setQueueName:@"TEST_Q2_NEW_3"];

    BFTask *answer = [sqs createQueue:createQueue];       
    NSLog(@"Status queue creation: %@ %@", answer.result, answer.error);

    AWSSQSReceiveMessageRequest *receiveMessageRequest = [[AWSSQSReceiveMessageRequest alloc] init];      
    receiveMessageRequest.QueueUrl = @"https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/TEST_Q";

    answer = [sqs receiveMessage:receiveMessageRequest];
    NSLog(@"Status messages received %@ %@", answer.result, answer.error);
```

The queue TEST_Q2_NEW_3 is created but the log message is:

Status queue creation: (null) (null)

No messages are fetched but in the SQS Management Console some has the status Messages in Flight. However, the log message is:

Status messages received (null) (null)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I did not completely understand BFTasks. The statement:

```
answer = [sqs receiveMessage:receiveMessageRequest];
```

actually starts a process in the background and when the log message is printed this task has not yet finished. To continue the processing of the result you have to use a continueWithBlock. The working code looks like this for the receive message functionality:

```
answer = [sqs receiveMessage:receiveMessageRequest];
[answer continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
    if (task.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Status received messages  %@ %@", answer.result, answer.error);
    } else if (task.error) {
        NSLog(@"Status received messages  %@ %@", answer.result, answer.error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Status received messages  %@ %@", answer.result, answer.error);
    }
    return nil;
}];
```

This is where I found the answer:
[BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS - GitHub](https://github.com/BoltsFramework/Bolts-iOS)